# Proposition into spoken language

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Given:

> $\sim( p \leftrightarrow   (q \vee r) )$
>
> $p:$ It's raining
>
> $q:$ The sun is shining
>
> $r:$ There are clouds in the sky.

Translate the proposition into spoken language.

Solution:

> It's false that it's raining if and only if the sun is shining or there
>   are clouds in the sky.

Would the solution above be okay?

Comment: Pretty much; I'd add a comma after "that".  You might also just say "It's not raining if and only if ...".

Comment: @James Okay, I get it! However, you suggested "It's not raining if and only if..." but isn't the negation symbol affecting the whole proposition? I understand by writing that only $p$ is being negated. Am I wrong?

Comment: @James: A comma after 'that' would definitely be ungrammatical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sim(A\leftrightarrow B)\equiv (A\leftrightarrow \sim B)$.

So $\sim(p\leftrightarrow(q\vee r)\equiv p\leftrightarrow (\sim q \wedge \sim r)$

So I'd suggest: It's raining if and only if the sun is not shining and there are no clouds in the sky.

[I wonder if your $r$ should be 'there are no clouds in the sky'.  That would make more sense.]

Answer (score 0):

Your translation is perfectly adequate. Another suggestion:

> **It's not the case that** it's raining if and only if the sun is shining or there are clouds in the sky.